# одно as "one thing"

Tags: числительные

I read the following excerpt:

> Он был арестован, без права переписка. Это значило **одно**: расстрел.

No doubt that **одно**, in this context, means *"just one thing"*.

Can **одно** also be used in an expression like *"I'll tell you one thing"*, when the purpose is to draw the attention of our listener to a particular detail?

Does "**я тебе скажу одно**" exist?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it's hard to message about it, 'cause it's more about intonation.

> Can одно also be used in an expression like "I'll tell you one thing",
>   when the purpose is to draw the attention of our listener to a
>   particular detail?

The short answer is yes, you can translate it like this.

But **я тебе скажу одно** is more like *I'll tell you **just one** thing*.

*I'll tell you one thing* is closer in meaning to **я тебе скажу одну вещь**

Comment: Personally, it feels that **"Я тебе одно скажу..."** flows a little bit better, than **"Я тебе скажу одно..."**

Answer (score 0):

> Он был арестован, без права переписка. Это значило одно: расстрел.

In this sence the 'одно' word should represent the 'единственный, последний' meaning.

> 'I'll tell you **one** thing'

here the 'one' would mean completely different 'this particular thing/ secret/ advice etc.'

> I'll tell you one thing is closer in meaning to я тебе скажу одну вещь

Exactly. По-русски так и будет: "Скажу тебе одну вещь."

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't exist. You'd want to distinguish between "one thing only"--"одно" and "one thing/some thing"--"кое-что / что-то".

In your case: "я тебе скажу кое-что" / "я тебе что-то скажу".

Verb and object may exchange places or not, depending on the emotional load and/or one's fancy); the variant(s) with "что-то" may be considered more colloquial.

Comment: Александр Розенбаум:
"Старина, скажу я тебе одно:
Спи всегда с открытым окном,
Чтоб чувствовать мир,
Его благодарно прими,
Все то, что в нем есть, ты прими, прими."

Рэй Брэдбери, Вино из одуванчиков:
"Я тебе одно скажу, Дуг: ужасно люблю вечером ложиться спать!"

Comment: @Mike Has: *when the purpose is to draw the attention of our listener to a **particular detail***

Comment: There was even a Soviet poster quoting Leonid Brezhev's speech: **Скажу одно: ...** You can use google books search for **скажу-одно** to get multiple matches.

Comment: AFAIU, the questioner doesn't want to say something definitely -- "скажу одно", but wants to tell about something -- "скажу кое-что".